# Angular Data-Binding results in NaN

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, data-binding

My problem is that the @Input() does not work properly for me. When I try to pass a value via data-binding it results in a NaN Error message.

I appreciate any form of help.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-button',
  templateUrl: './nav-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-button.component.scss'],
})

export class NavButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() page: String; <-- results in NaN - message

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  goToPage(): void {
    console.log(this.page);
    this.router.navigate([this.page]);
  }
}
```

My "View". Here I pass the data to my "NavButtonComponent"-class.

```
<ion-content>
  <app-nav-button [page]="food-list"></app-nav-button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Try using `string` and not `String` for the input datatype?

Comment: what is `food-list`?

Comment: @R.Richards no, didnt work.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm it's just a string. The goal should be that the variable "page" gets this said string at runtime and I can work with it.

Comment: Are you sure the string has the correct value? where is it set?

Comment: [page]="’food-list’" (note the additional quotes). And indeed, use string as type, not String.

Comment: @MikeOne Share code for how food-list is created!

Comment: @NarenMurali - I’m not the OP. But I’m pretty sure he just wants to pass in that actual string, because it cannot be a component variable.

Comment: @MikeOne sorry my bad

Comment: No probs :-) ……

Comment: <app-nav-button page="food-list"></app-nav-button> try like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was `<app-nav-button page="food-list"></app-nav-button>`.
Removing the [] was the solution. Thank you @cfprabhu !

Comment: When you use `[page]="food-list"` Angular ask about a variable in your .ts called "food-list", que you use `page="food-list"` Angular gets the "literal" "food-list". Another is `[page]="'food-list'"` (enclosed the literal between single quotes)

Comment: @Eliseo this is very useful knowledge that will help not only me but other people reading this post! Thanks again for sharing your wisdom!